# Splitting 8 elements from one list into the first element of another C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, loops

one a integer list and one a string list. The integer list's length will always be a multiple of 8. I would like to put the first 8 integers from my integer list into the first element of a string list, then loop and put the next 8 into the second element of the string list and so on. I have made an attempt, I currently have an error on the Add method as string doesn't have an add extension? Also I'm not sure if the way I have done it using loops is correct, any advice would be helpful.

List1 is my integer list

List2 is my string list

```
string x = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < List1.Count/8; i++) {

                for(int i2 = 0; i2 < i2+8; i2+=8)
                {
                    x = Convert.ToString(List1[i2]);

                    List2[i].Add(h);
                } 
        }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs.

Comment: First element of string list will be a string. So how are you planning to add 8 numbers in to one string? Can you give an example of how the string list should look like when you add numbers to it? `List[I]` gives you a single string and you can not add another string to a string.that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: @GrantWinney Except when `i2` is within 8 of `int.MaxValue` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using something like that

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
var list2 = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count / 8; i++)
{
    list2.Add(string.Concat(list1.Skip(i * 8).Take(8)));
}

// list2[0] = "12345678"
// list2[1] = "910111213141516"
```

A slightly more complicated approach, which only iterates once over `list1` (would work with IEnumerable would be sth. like this:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 }.AsEnumerable();
var list2 = new List<string>();

var i = 0;
var nextValue = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var integer in list1)
{
    nextValue.Append(integer);
    i++;

    if (i != 0 && i % 8 == 0)
    {
        list2.Add(nextValue.ToString());
        nextValue.Clear();
    }
}

// could add remaining items if count of list1 is not a multiple of 8
// if (nextValue.Length > 0)
// {
//     list2.Add(nextValue.ToString());
// }
```

Comment: as long as main source implements `IList` or `IReadOnlyList` this algorithm is good. other wise MoreLinq approach would be faster and much better.

Comment: i added a no-lib-example which should only iterate `list1` once

Comment: yes. Take and Skip also iterates `list1` once. if you check the [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Skip.cs,90ccdbd47b57182e) it uses special enumerator called `ListPartition`. this will jump to the given position. but if your main source was not `IList` then it would have to use the slow enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it, you can implement your own general purpose `Batch` extension method. Good practice to understand [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), [enumerators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx), [iterators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators), [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx) and c#'s [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions):

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, 
    int batchCount,
    bool throwOnPartialBatch = false)
{
    IEnumerable<T> nextBatch(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
    {
        var counter = 0;

        do
        {
           yield return enumerator.Current;
           counter += 1;

        } while (counter < batchCount && enumerator.MoveNext());

        if (throwOnPartialBatch && counter != batchCount) //numers.Count % batchCount is not zero.
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid batch size.");
    }

    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    if (batchCount < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(batchCount));

    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return nextBatch(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Using it is rather trivial:

```
var ii = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
var ss = ii.Batch(4, true)
           .Select(b => string.Join(", ", b))
```

And sure enough, the output is:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (listOfintergers.Count() > 0)
        {
            var first8elements = listOfintergers.ConvertAll(t=>t.ToString()).Take(8);
            listOfStrings.Add(string.Concat(first8elements));
            listOfintergers = listOfintergers.Skip(8).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.